# Left join query confusion with two tables

Tags: sql, left-join

How can join these two tables using left join query, `Activity_Table` and `Custom_field_Table` to get below the output table?

This is Activity_Table

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| Activity_id | Activity_name | Pos_id   | Op_id   |
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| 1           | XXX           |1012      |1024     |
| 2           | YYY           |1010      |1016     |
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

This is Custom_field_Table

```
+------+------+
| Id   | Name |
+------+------+
| 1012 | AAA  |
| 1010 | BBB  |
| 1016 | CCC  |
| 1024 | DDD  |
+------+------+
```

Output table that I want:

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| Activity_id | Activity_name | Pos_name | Op_name |  
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
| 1           | XXX           | AAA      | DDD     |  
| 2           | YYY           | BBB      | CCC     |  
+-------------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: You should edit the question and show what you have tried.

Comment: you need to use alias' for the different left joins you make, and refer to the columns with the alias in the query when joining and selecting.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  to `left join` twice:

```
select 
    a.activity_id,
    a.activity_name,
    cp.name pos_name,
    co.name op_name
from activity_table a
left join custom_field_table cp on cp.id = a.pos_id
left join custom_field_table co on co.id = a.op_id
```

Answer (score 0):

@Savi

```
select 
    activity_id, activity_name, a.name pos_name, b.name op_name 
from 
    activity_table, custom_field_table a , custom_field_table b  
where 
    pos_id=a.id and op_id=b.id 
order by activity_id
```

In the above since you are using a common reference table you need to do join twice of the same table. with two different references. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 joints:

```
Select Activity_id,Activity_name,tmp1.name as Pos_name,tmp2.name as op_name from Activity_table at
left join custom_field_table tmp1 on tmp1.id = at.pos_id
left join custom_field_table tmp2 on tmp2.id = at.op_id
order by activity_id
```

[See the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4491859/4)

Answer (score 0):

This query would get you the output you need. But you need to be more specific on what you tried (the requirement).

```
SELECT 
    x.* 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.activity_id, a.activity_name,
        IF(a.pos_id = b.id, b.name, null) AS pos_name,
        IF(a.op_id = b.id, b.name, null) AS op_name
    FROM 
        activity_table a 
    JOIN
        custom_field_table b 
) x
WHERE 
    x.pos_name IS NOT NULL AND x.op_name IS NOT NULL;
```

However, the above query would be a cross join as there isn't any join condition. The where clause (in this query) would ensure that you get only the rows in which both - pos_name and op_name are not empty.